# Parsing sqlexception error messages

Tags: sql-server

I'm using C# for end user forms,and what i want to do is to parse the error messages I get from the SQL server.Normally the end user gets the messages like in the picture.Is there a way to parse this and to give the end user what he understands instead of that gibberish there? (like "The Name Test is not permitted in this context .... " as in the picture.)

[sql error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfEFO.png)
[image]

Comment: exception.ToString() will produce a string like your picture, generally.  exception.Message will include just the error message, no stack trace.

Comment: Converted to an official answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exception.ToString() will produce a string like your picture, generally. exception.Message will include just the error message, no stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Use Exception.ToString to display a full stack trace.  Use Exception.Message to get just the text description part of the error.

In addition, you can look at the [SqlException.Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.class.aspx) and [SqlException.Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) properties to make informed decisions about how to handle these exceptions in your code.  The SqlException.Number property will correspond to an entry in the [sys.messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187382%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) view.  1205, for example, is the number for a deadlock exception.  And if SqlException.Class = 11, then that is a concurrency exception.

The [SqlException.Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors.aspx) property is a list of SqlError objects that contain more detailed information about individual [errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.aspx).  Since a single RPC call to the database can result in multiple exceptions, review these errors to see everything that happened.

Answer (score 0):

When reporting errors in SQL there is always a dilemma where the SQL message needs to convey to the developer what happen, but also provide useful information to a user of the application. We developed a technique of structuring the SQL message into an XML string that provides all the useful information about the error, which allows the caller to use as required. You can see my article on this technique on Code Project at the URL below:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1076477/SQL-Server-Structure-Error-Handling